# Image is black when loaded (jquery Jack Moore's image zoom plugin involved)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I have a dynamically added image but when it's loaded it's black (I know it's loaded because I tried putting a loading gif and set it to be removed when image is loaded, and the gif didn't show up). I exit the window I created (just a big div block) then enter again and the image displays normally.

I basically created a function called appendImg() to add images dynamically as seen below, and these images all use Jack Moore's jquery zoom plugin I installed. This plugin basically allows me to zoom in on the image when I click on it, so it requires me to create an id for the plugin then append the image into the id.

How can I have the image show up normally without closing and opening my div? Right now I'm still coding on desktop, but I will use Github to publish the website later, will that make the image load faster? Thanks.

I tried appending an image normally without using the plugin like this and it shows up right away, so it has to be because of the plugin that's not making the image show up right away:

```
function appendNormalImg(imgName){
    var image = document.createElement("img");                  
    image.src = imgName;
    image.alt = "image";
    image.setAttribute("class", "normalImage");            

    $(".infoContent").append(image);                   
}
```

```
function appendImg(imgName){
    zoomNum+=1;   //variable is initialized at top of the javascript file
    var zoomNumString = zoomNum.toString();          //create id name for new zoom class
    var zoomID = "zoomId" + zoomNumString;

    var newZoomClass = document.createElement("div");         //create new zoom class for each image
    newZoomClass.setAttribute("class", "zoom");
    newZoomClass.setAttribute("id", zoomID);            //new ID for zoom container (since I may use this function multiple times to add multiple images)

    $(".infoContent").append(newZoomClass);

    var image = document.createElement("img");                  //create img element
    image.src = imgName;
    image.alt = "image";
    var imgID = "imgID" + zoomNumString;
    image.setAttribute("id", imgID);            //new ID for image to get width below (again, because I want multiple images)

    zoomID = "#"+zoomID;
    imgID = "#"+imgID;

    $(zoomID).append(image);                   //appendchild image to specific zoom ID

    var imgHeight = $(imgID).height();
    $(zoomID).height(imgHeight);

    var imgWidth = $(imgID).width();
    $(zoomID).width(imgWidth);

    $(document).ready(function(){                                //jquery plugin zoom function for zooming in on picture
        $(zoomID).zoom({on:'click', magnify:1,url:false, touch:true});
    });

    $(imgID).ready(function(){                                    
        $("#loader").remove();
    });
}
```

Comment: Not enough details were provided to answer the question. It could just look that way do to a number of reasons.

Comment: Are you use **Lazyload** images?

Comment: @RubixOverflow No

Comment: @StackSlave I added more details to my question, would you mind looking over it? Thanks.

Comment: Examples are clear at https://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/ . Follow them.